# Change hyphen/dash for vertical line in menu

Tags: menus, themes

I have the theme Blaskan installed. I have a child theme installed also, but I cannot seem to change the hyphens/dashes to vertical lines `|` in my menu for this theme.

Any suggestion would be appreciated?

Comment: Have you reviewed the theme templates? Look for the code that represents the menu. Check the WordPress.org codex and start your research here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Navigation_Menus

Answer (score 0):

If you mean in the footer?  I looked at the Blaskan Theme, and saw hyphens in the footer menu.

To change that... use CSS.  Make the

```
#footer-nav li:before {
      content: " \007C ";
      font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

That will change it from a hyphen. To a |

To make it space out better, you may want to add

```
      padding-right: .4em;
```